# Stop Jenkins from Converting Paths on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, cygwin, jenkins

I am attempting to run a Windows 8.1 machine as a "dumb slave". I am using Cygwin and SSHD to provide a working environment that functions great when I SSH into this machine. However, I am having issues with Jenkins trying to do too much. When Jenkins connects to this Windows machine it correctly identifies it as running Windows 8.1. That's great that it can do that, but unfortunately it decides, without prompting or giving me the option, to convert paths from UNIX style to Windows style.

Consequently, I am dealing with two problems:

1. Jenkins checks out from my SVN repository to the wrong location on the Windows host.
2. Jenkins cannot launch shell scripts that start with the appropriate shebang '#!/usr/bin/bash'

The checkout issue starts innocently enough. When I check the console output I see:

```
Building remotely on Geidi_Prime in workspace /home/daeden/issm/jenkins/workspace/Win8/label/Geidi_Prime
```

This is the correct path and I would be very happy if Jenkins would actually checkout to this path. However, I then see:

```
Checking out a fresh workspace because there's no workspace at C:\home\daeden\issm\jenkins\workspace\Win8\label\Geidi_Prime
```

This is almost comically the incorrect path. Not only is this the incorrect translation of the previous path, but it is also an unnecessary and unwanted translation.

My second issue is caused by the same unwarranted address translation and results int he following output:

```
[Geidi_Prime] $ /usr/bin/bash C:\Users\daeden\hudson5172208145209834785.sh
The system cannot find the file specified
FATAL: command execution failed
```

If the script in question was simply placed in the correct location

```
/home/daeden/hudson5172208145209834785.sh
```

I believe this would work like a charm. Does anyone know how to stop this Jenkins behavior, or how to fool Jenkins into thinking that this is not a Windows machine?